# Pandas - how to sort a DataFrame via custom sorting of a column?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

Below is the output for my DataFrame. I would like to sort the DataFrame by the column animals and subsequently by day. How can I sort animals in the following order: dogs, pigs, cats?  Thanks.

```
index     animals     day     number 
0          dogs        1         3
1          cats        2         1
2          dogs        3         4
3          pigs        4         0
4          pigs        5         6
5          cats        6         1
```

Comment: See the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the columns to sort by as a list -

```
In [30]: df.sort(['animals', 'day'])
Out[30]: 
  animals  day  number
1    cats    2       1
5    cats    6       1
0    dogs    1       3
2    dogs    3       4
3    pigs    4       0
4    pigs    5       6
```

The order of columns determines how the dataframe gets sorted first, and how ties are broken.

Comment: Thank you.  How would it be done if I wanted to order or the animals column to be dogs, pigs, cats?

Comment: @user3133136: dogs-pigs-cats is not a natural ordering, so the sort function won't handle that (unless you map those values to the ordering you desire). You can use the `ascending` option to change the order - `df.sort(['animals', 'day'], ascending=[False, True])`, if you want animals to be reverse sorted and day to be incrementally sorted.